# Case When Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Every name has at least 4 different `td`'s. When `01` or `02` is attached to that name, I want to change the `td` to the `td` from the latest pay date for that name.

However, I keep getting a `NULL` value. What is wrong with this query?

```
SELECT
    name, 
    CASE WHEN td in ('01', '02') 
         THEN (SELECT TOP 1 td 
               WHERE td not in ('01', '02') 
               ORDER BY paydate DESC) 
         ELSE td 
    END
FROM tdtest
```

Comment: What tells you that there is something wrong with the query? Results? Error message? ...?

Comment: Technically, nothing is wrong with the query I guess. But I keep getting a NULL. I want to get a different td.

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that **returns one atomic value** - it is *not* a statement, not able to control the flow of code execution etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a from clause and a correlation condition in the subquery.

Without a from clause, the `td` in the subselect is the same as the `td` in the outer select, in other words one of `'01'` or `'02'` and the where clause test eliminates the row, resulting in a NULL.

```
SELECT
    name, 
    CASE WHEN td in ('01', '02') 
         THEN (SELECT TOP 1 td
               FROM TdTest InnerTDTest -- table to look in
               WHERE InnerTDTest.Name = TDTest.Name -- only look at matching rows.
               AND td not in ('01', '02') 
               ORDER BY paydate DESC) 
         ELSE td 
    END
FROM tdtest
```